# Make field editable after date

Tags: entities, datetime

Is it possible to make a field either editable or appear after a date?

I have a content type with a Title, Date and 'Winning Numbers' field. The winning numbers field should only be fillable/editable AFTER the Date in the date field has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You van achieve this with hook_field_access (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7). You can check the date value against current date from the $entity object and then set permissions.